# Issues with beamer document class

Tags: beamer, errors

I’m trying to make a presentation in Latex for the first time. To get started, I copied the following code from Wikipedia:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\title{Presentation on XXX topic}
\author{AAA}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is the first slide}
        Here you can put any text/equation etc. 
        $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.      
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is the second slide}
        \framesubtitle{A bit more information about this}
        Some random text.       
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \bbl@cs
           {beforestart}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.2 \bbl@cs
           {beforestart}
End of file on the terminal!
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it? The reason I ask is that I don't encounter any problems with the code you posted on my system (MacTeX2023, all udpates applied; LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1; beamer 2023/05/15 v3.70).

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Can you a) try to delete all the auxiliary files and recompile from scratch (the error looks a bit like some left-over from a bibliography) and b) show your .log file (if step a did not solve your problem)

Comment: Did you use a file you've previously had some other content in? That looks very much like an `.aux` file 'stray'

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Your first suggestion worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was not caused by the material posted in the query.

Comment: @Federico You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!